# Consequences of small bank debt in EU as citizen of another country

Tags: credit-score, bank-account, debt, european-union, france

I have a bank account in France that I created when I lived there about 10-8 years ago. A year ago this account started charging a monthly fee that didn't exist before, and then I started trying to close the account. However, answers from the bank usually took weeks to months to say which documents I needed to close the account and transfer my remaining credit, and after a few months of fees I entered in negative balance (now 25 euros).

One of the "conseillers" informed me that after 3 months they would terminate my account with unpaid debt, and in that case I would be "fiché" and I would not be able to open another account in the bank anymore.

The regular process has been so tiresome that I am considering just waiting them to terminate the account instead of paying that fee debt that happened due to delays on bank answers, but I am afraid of other consequences of that. May I have difficulties in doing any other thing in France or in the EU because of that in the future? I do not have intentions of opening another account in the same bank, which was the consequence the bank employee informed me about.